# While NDK-BUILD (with dlib library ) in android studio, the following error has shown

Tags: android, opencv, native, dlib

I am trying to use dlib,opencv and android studio in a project.While doing ndk-build the following error has shown

Part of error

```
error: undefined reference to dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
error: undefined reference to 'dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)
 error: undefined reference to 'dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)
....................
error: undefined reference to 'dlib::base64::decode(std::istream&, std::ostream&) const
 error: undefined reference to 'dlib::base64::~base64()
```

**Content of Android.mk file is**

```
*LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
WITH_CUDA=OFF
include /home/sysadmin/ANDROID_PROG_ENVIRONMENTS/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES = $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=/home/sysadmin/Android/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=/home/sysadmin/Android/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=/home/sysadmin/Android/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d/include/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=/home/sysadmin/Android/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/include/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=/home/sysadmin/Android/opencv-3.1.0/modules/flann/include/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=/dlib/dlib/entropy_decoder_model/
LIBS=/dlib/dlib/
LOCAL_MODULE    := ImageProcessing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = ImageProcessing.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += head_pose_estimation.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm -llog -ldl -lz
LDFLAGS =-ldlib
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS +=-lpthread -lX11 -ggdb  -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)*
```

Answer (score 1):

Add whatever cpp files it is asking  as LOCAL_SRC_FILES in your Android.mk  file from dlib source folder. For example for two link errors shown in your case,do the following step

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../dlib/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp \
                   ../dlib/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp \
```

These are basically link errors that your project is expecting from dlib